# Can covariates in a Cox Proportional Hazard model be combined in any meaningful way?

Tags: survival, hazard

I have a study which gives the hazard ratios for certain interventions like:

- Intervention 1, HR: .9
- Intervention 2, HR: .8
- ...

Is there any way in which I could predict the relative risk for e.g. someone who has intervention 1 and 2?

I think if I assume that the interventions are independent, then the HR of doing both is just the product of the individuals' HRs, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HR of doing both is the product of the separate HRs if you assume that there's no *[interaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_%28statistics%29)* between the two effects on the multiplicative scale. [Independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29) is a separate issue from interaction.